# transform xml using xslt; iterate over children based on value

Tags: xml, xslt

My input xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
    <e class="object">
        <children class="array">
            <e class="object">
                <children class="array">
                    <e class="object">
                        <id type="number">3</id>
                        <leaf type="boolean">true</leaf>
                        <node type="string">0+0+0</node>
                        <o type="number">18265</o>
                        <text type="string">Bridge Calibration</text>
                        <url type="string">59739.htm</url>
                    </e>
                    <e class="object">
                        <id type="number">4</id>
                        <leaf type="boolean">true</leaf>
                        <node type="string">0+0+1</node>
                        <o type="number">18266</o>
                        <text type="string">External key pad</text>
                        <url type="string">59740.htm#o18266</url>
                    </e>
                </children>
                <id type="number">2</id>
                <node type="string">0+0</node>
                <o type="number">59738</o>
                <text type="string">Specific Test.Lab Combined Modes add-in</text>
                <url type="string">59738.htm</url>
            </e>
        </children>
        <id type="number">1</id>
        <node type="string">0</node>
        <o type="number">61136</o>
        <text type="string">The LMS Test.Lab Combined Modes workbook</text>
        <url type="string">59737.htm</url>
    </e>
</a>
```

I want the output to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<topicMap id="TheLMSTest.LabCombinedModesworkbook">
   <title>The LMS Test.Lab Combined Modes workbook</title>
          <topicRef>
      <metadata>
         <topicInformation/>
      </metadata>
      <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
                  href="libraryPath:LMS-import-en_US/topicLibrary/D59738.xml"/>
   </topicRef>
   <topicRef>
      <metadata>
         <topicInformation/>
      </metadata>
      <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
                  href="libraryPath:LMS-import-en_US/topicLibrary/D59739.xml"/>
   </topicRef>
   </topicMap>
```

So, main points are:

1. I want the output topicref information in order of input id values.The information corresponding to id=2 should appear first and so on. The information corresponding to id=1 should be used for topicMap and title elements.
2. I want xi:include href to contain the value as per url but only those url elements that have no # in the value.

I understand that the question might not be very clear. Please feel free to ask more information if required.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is very unclear.  The only thing in the input that appears in the output is the title and two of the four URL fragments.  Is the rest of the output static?  If not, what populates `topicInformation`, and what happened to the two URL fragments that didn't get copied to the output? How did you decide which ones to copy?

Answer (score 0):

If (!) I understand this correctly, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="first-obj" select="//e[id = 1]" />
    <topicMap id="{$first-obj/text}">
        <title>
            <xsl:value-of select="$first-obj/text"/>
        </title>
        <xsl:for-each select="//e[id > 1][not(contains(url, '#'))]">
            <topicRef>
                <metadata>
                    <topicInformation/>
                </metadata>
                <xi:include href="libraryPath:LMS-import-en_US/topicLibrary/{url}"/>
            </topicRef>     
        </xsl:for-each>
    </topicMap>
    <xsl:copy>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this would return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topicMap xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" id="The LMS Test.Lab Combined Modes workbook">
   <title>The LMS Test.Lab Combined Modes workbook</title>
   <topicRef>
      <metadata>
         <topicInformation/>
      </metadata>
      <xi:include href="libraryPath:LMS-import-en_US/topicLibrary/59738.htm"/>
   </topicRef>
   <topicRef>
      <metadata>
         <topicInformation/>
      </metadata>
      <xi:include href="libraryPath:LMS-import-en_US/topicLibrary/59739.htm"/>
   </topicRef>
</topicMap>
```

I did not discover the logic by which `"TheLMSTest.LabCombinedModesworkbook"` should be produced from the given input.